# Why does JIT order affect performance?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, compiler-construction, jit

Why does the order in which C# methods in .NET 4.0 are just-in-time compiled affect how quickly they execute? For example, consider two equivalent methods:

```
public static void SingleLineTest()
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();
    int count = 0;
    for (uint i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++i) {
        count += i % 16 == 0 ? 1 : 0;
    }
    stopwatch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Single-line test --> Count: {0}, Time: {1}", count, stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}

public static void MultiLineTest()
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();
    int count = 0;
    for (uint i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++i) {
        var isMultipleOf16 = i % 16 == 0;
        count += isMultipleOf16 ? 1 : 0;
    }
    stopwatch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Multi-line test  --> Count: {0}, Time: {1}", count, stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

The only difference is the introduction of a local variable, which affects the assembly code generated and the loop performance. Why that is the case is a [question in its own right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369421/why-does-adding-local-variables-make-net-code-slower).

Possibly even stranger is that on x86 (but not x64), the order that the methods are invoked has around a 20% impact on performance. Invoke the methods like this...

```
static void Main()
{
    SingleLineTest();
    MultiLineTest();
}
```

...and `SingleLineTest` is faster. (Compile using the x86 Release configuration, ensuring that "Optimize code" setting is enabled, and run the test from outside VS2010.)  But reverse the order...

```
static void Main()
{
    MultiLineTest();
    SingleLineTest();
}
```

...and both methods take the same time (almost, but not quite, as long as `MultiLineTest` before). (When running this test, it's useful to add some additional calls to `SingleLineTest` and `MultiLineTest` to get additional samples. How many and what order doesn't matter, except for which method is called first.)

Finally, to demonstrate that JIT order is important, leave `MultiLineTest` first, but force  `SingleLineTest` to be JITed first...

```
static void Main()
{
    RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod(typeof(Program).GetMethod("SingleLineTest").MethodHandle);
    MultiLineTest();
    SingleLineTest();
}
```

Now, `SingleLineTest` is faster again.

If you turn off "Suppress JIT optimization on module load" in VS2010, you can put a breakpoint in `SingleLineTest` and see that the assembly code in the loop is the same regardless of JIT order; however, the assembly code at the beginning of the method varies. But how this matters when the bulk of the time is spent in the loop is perplexing.

A [sample project demonstrating this behavior](https://github.com/breyed/PerfTest) is on github.

It's not clear how this behavior affects real-world applications. One concern is that it can make performance tuning volatile, depending on the order methods happen to be first called. Problems of this sort would be difficult to detect with a profiler. Once you found the hotspots and optimized their algorithms, it would be hard to know without a lot of guess and check whether additional speedup is possible by JITing methods early.

**Update:** See also the [Microsoft Connect entry](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/742527/jit-optimizer-does-not-perform-loop-top-alignment) for this issue.

Comment: "...has around a 20% impact on performance" I got around 8%

Comment: Is the alignment (of the actual instructions) the same?  Either being JITted following the other method, or the minor change to the preamble, could really screw with the alignment.

Comment: @lukas On two computers each with Intel Core i5s, I got an average of 1412ms and 1490ms for the `SingleLineTest` and 1773ms and 1792ms for `MultiLineTest`. This works out to speedups of 26% and 20%. For each computer, the standard deviation for the speedup came to 2%. I would have expected to see some difference between machines, but the 8% is surprising.

Comment: On a mobile Core i7 (1st gen), I get about 2000 and 2400, so a similar 20%.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Please note that I do not trust the "Suppress JIT optimization on module load" option, I spawn the process without debugging and attach my debugger after the JIT has run.

In the version where single-line runs faster, this is `Main`:

```
        SingleLineTest();
00000000  push        ebp 
00000001  mov         ebp,esp 
00000003  call        dword ptr ds:[0019380Ch] 
            MultiLineTest();
00000009  call        dword ptr ds:[00193818h] 
            SingleLineTest();
0000000f  call        dword ptr ds:[0019380Ch] 
            MultiLineTest();
00000015  call        dword ptr ds:[00193818h] 
            SingleLineTest();
0000001b  call        dword ptr ds:[0019380Ch] 
            MultiLineTest();
00000021  call        dword ptr ds:[00193818h] 
00000027  pop         ebp 
        }
00000028  ret
```

Note that `MultiLineTest` has been placed on an 8 byte boundary, and `SingleLineTest` on a 4 byte boundary.

Here's `Main` for the version where both run at the same speed:

```
            MultiLineTest();
00000000  push        ebp 
00000001  mov         ebp,esp 
00000003  call        dword ptr ds:[00153818h] 

            SingleLineTest();
00000009  call        dword ptr ds:[0015380Ch] 
            MultiLineTest();
0000000f  call        dword ptr ds:[00153818h] 
            SingleLineTest();
00000015  call        dword ptr ds:[0015380Ch] 
            MultiLineTest();
0000001b  call        dword ptr ds:[00153818h] 
            SingleLineTest();
00000021  call        dword ptr ds:[0015380Ch] 
            MultiLineTest();
00000027  call        dword ptr ds:[00153818h] 
0000002d  pop         ebp 
        }
0000002e  ret
```

Amazingly, the addresses chosen by the JIT are **identical** in the last 4 digits, even though it allegedly processed them in the opposite order.  Not sure I believe that any more.

More digging is necessary.  I think it was mentioned that the code before the loop wasn't exactly the same in both versions?  Going to investigate.

Here's the "slow" version of `SingleLineTest` (and I checked, the last digits of the function address haven't changed).

```
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
00000000  push        ebp 
00000001  mov         ebp,esp 
00000003  push        edi 
00000004  push        esi 
00000005  push        ebx 
00000006  mov         ecx,7A5A2C68h 
0000000b  call        FFF91EA0 
00000010  mov         esi,eax 
00000012  mov         dword ptr [esi+4],0 
00000019  mov         dword ptr [esi+8],0 
00000020  mov         byte ptr [esi+14h],0 
00000024  mov         dword ptr [esi+0Ch],0 
0000002b  mov         dword ptr [esi+10h],0 
            stopwatch.Start();
00000032  cmp         byte ptr [esi+14h],0 
00000036  jne         00000047 
00000038  call        7A22B314 
0000003d  mov         dword ptr [esi+0Ch],eax 
00000040  mov         dword ptr [esi+10h],edx 
00000043  mov         byte ptr [esi+14h],1 
            int count = 0;
00000047  xor         edi,edi 
            for (uint i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++i) {
00000049  xor         edx,edx 
                count += i % 16 == 0 ? 1 : 0;
0000004b  mov         eax,edx 
0000004d  and         eax,0Fh 
00000050  test        eax,eax 
00000052  je          00000058 
00000054  xor         eax,eax 
00000056  jmp         0000005D 
00000058  mov         eax,1 
0000005d  add         edi,eax 
            for (uint i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++i) {
0000005f  inc         edx 
00000060  cmp         edx,3B9ACA00h 
00000066  jb          0000004B 
            }
            stopwatch.Stop();
00000068  mov         ecx,esi 
0000006a  call        7A23F2C0 
            Console.WriteLine("Single-line test --> Count: {0}, Time: {1}", count, stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
0000006f  mov         ecx,797C29B4h 
00000074  call        FFF91EA0 
00000079  mov         ecx,eax 
0000007b  mov         dword ptr [ecx+4],edi 
0000007e  mov         ebx,ecx 
00000080  mov         ecx,797BA240h 
00000085  call        FFF91EA0 
0000008a  mov         edi,eax 
0000008c  mov         ecx,esi 
0000008e  call        7A23ABE8 
00000093  push        edx 
00000094  push        eax 
00000095  push        0 
00000097  push        2710h 
0000009c  call        783247EC 
000000a1  mov         dword ptr [edi+4],eax 
000000a4  mov         dword ptr [edi+8],edx 
000000a7  mov         esi,edi 
000000a9  call        793C6F40 
000000ae  push        ebx 
000000af  push        esi 
000000b0  mov         ecx,eax 
000000b2  mov         edx,dword ptr ds:[03392034h] 
000000b8  mov         eax,dword ptr [ecx] 
000000ba  mov         eax,dword ptr [eax+3Ch] 
000000bd  call        dword ptr [eax+1Ch] 
000000c0  pop         ebx 
        }
000000c1  pop         esi 
000000c2  pop         edi 
000000c3  pop         ebp 
000000c4  ret
```

And the "fast" version:

```
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
00000000  push        ebp 
00000001  mov         ebp,esp 
00000003  push        edi 
00000004  push        esi 
00000005  push        ebx 
00000006  mov         ecx,7A5A2C68h 
0000000b  call        FFE11F70 
00000010  mov         esi,eax 
00000012  mov         ecx,esi 
00000014  call        7A1068BC 
            stopwatch.Start();
00000019  cmp         byte ptr [esi+14h],0 
0000001d  jne         0000002E 
0000001f  call        7A12B3E4 
00000024  mov         dword ptr [esi+0Ch],eax 
00000027  mov         dword ptr [esi+10h],edx 
0000002a  mov         byte ptr [esi+14h],1 
            int count = 0;
0000002e  xor         edi,edi 
            for (uint i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++i) {
00000030  xor         edx,edx 
                count += i % 16 == 0 ? 1 : 0;
00000032  mov         eax,edx 
00000034  and         eax,0Fh 
00000037  test        eax,eax 
00000039  je          0000003F 
0000003b  xor         eax,eax 
0000003d  jmp         00000044 
0000003f  mov         eax,1 
00000044  add         edi,eax 
            for (uint i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++i) {
00000046  inc         edx 
00000047  cmp         edx,3B9ACA00h 
0000004d  jb          00000032 
            }
            stopwatch.Stop();
0000004f  mov         ecx,esi 
00000051  call        7A13F390 
            Console.WriteLine("Single-line test --> Count: {0}, Time: {1}", count, stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
00000056  mov         ecx,797C29B4h 
0000005b  call        FFE11F70 
00000060  mov         ecx,eax 
00000062  mov         dword ptr [ecx+4],edi 
00000065  mov         ebx,ecx 
00000067  mov         ecx,797BA240h 
0000006c  call        FFE11F70 
00000071  mov         edi,eax 
00000073  mov         ecx,esi 
00000075  call        7A13ACB8 
0000007a  push        edx 
0000007b  push        eax 
0000007c  push        0 
0000007e  push        2710h 
00000083  call        782248BC 
00000088  mov         dword ptr [edi+4],eax 
0000008b  mov         dword ptr [edi+8],edx 
0000008e  mov         esi,edi 
00000090  call        792C7010 
00000095  push        ebx 
00000096  push        esi 
00000097  mov         ecx,eax 
00000099  mov         edx,dword ptr ds:[03562030h] 
0000009f  mov         eax,dword ptr [ecx] 
000000a1  mov         eax,dword ptr [eax+3Ch] 
000000a4  call        dword ptr [eax+1Ch] 
000000a7  pop         ebx 
        }
000000a8  pop         esi 
000000a9  pop         edi 
000000aa  pop         ebp 
000000ab  ret
```

Just the loops, fast on the left, slow on the right:

```
00000030  xor         edx,edx                 00000049  xor         edx,edx 
00000032  mov         eax,edx                 0000004b  mov         eax,edx 
00000034  and         eax,0Fh                 0000004d  and         eax,0Fh 
00000037  test        eax,eax                 00000050  test        eax,eax 
00000039  je          0000003F                00000052  je          00000058 
0000003b  xor         eax,eax                 00000054  xor         eax,eax 
0000003d  jmp         00000044                00000056  jmp         0000005D 
0000003f  mov         eax,1                   00000058  mov         eax,1 
00000044  add         edi,eax                 0000005d  add         edi,eax 
00000046  inc         edx                     0000005f  inc         edx 
00000047  cmp         edx,3B9ACA00h           00000060  cmp         edx,3B9ACA00h 
0000004d  jb          00000032                00000066  jb          0000004B
```

The instructions are *identical* (being relative jumps, the machine code is identical even though the disassembly shows different addresses), but the alignment is different.  There are three jumps.  the `je` loading a constant `1` is aligned in the slow version and not in the fast version, but it hardly matters, since that jump is only taken 1/16 of the time.  The other two jumps ( `jmp` after loading a constant zero, and `jb` repeating the entire loop) are taken millions more times, and are aligned in the "fast" version.

I think this is the smoking gun.

Comment: "the last digits of the function address haven't changed" true for me as well, but my disassembly output is 104 lines long where this is one 75.

Comment: yeah. Build tab: target is x86, optimize code is checked and I got the asm from Debug -> Windows -> Disassembly

Comment: @lukas: Would you be so kind as to paste it into an "answer" or on pastebin/ideone/whatever, so I can see what you have?

Comment: Are you talking about 4 byte alignment? The "fast" jmp is only align one, isn't it?

Comment: @lukas: `jmp 44h` and `jb 32h` are both better aligned than `jmp 5Dh` and `jb 4Bh`.  Oh sorry, I got the end-of-loop and mid-loop conditionals mixed up didn't I?  Description fixed.

Comment: Related question: [Why should code be aligned to even-address boundaries on x86?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4909563/145173)

Answer (score 0):

So for a definitive answer... I suspect we would need to dig into the dis-assembly.

However, I have a guess.  The compiler for the `SingleLineTest()` stores each result of the equation on the stack and pops each value as needed.  However, the `MultiLineTest()` may be storing values and having to access them from there.  This could cause a few clock cycles to be missed.  Where as grabbing the values off the stack will keep it in a register.

Interestingly, changing the order of the function compilation may be adjusting the garbage collector's actions.  Because `isMultipleOf16` is defined within the loop, it may be be handled funny.  You may want to move the definition outside of the loop and see what that changes...

Comment: Since `isMultipleOf16` is a value type, it is stored on the stack and isn't touched by the GC. Other than for the stopwatch and console output, the GC shouldn't be doing anything.

Comment: " Since isMultipleOf16 is a value type, it is stored on the stack and isn't touched by the GC" That is incorrect. There is no such guarantee. JITer can move value type to the heap. But I guess that's not the case here.

Comment: Would it make a difference if the definition was moved out of the loop?

Comment: @Andrew: I tried, and moving `isMultipleOf16` out of the loop didn't matter. It seems that you can count on the compiler for that much, at least.

Comment: @Andrew: I did look at the disassembly and put my thoughts about it in the body of the question above. I included tips for how to check it out yourself if you're so inclined (easiest is to grab a Zip of the sample project off github and play with it).

Comment: @EdwardBrey: OK.  I'm not in front of a computer currently that I would be able to go and actually compile and run the code currently.  I'll try and look at it tomorrow at some point... my interest has been stirred.

Answer (score 0):

My time is 2400 and 2600 on i5-2410M 2,3Ghz 4GB ram 64bit Win 7.

Here is my output: Single first

After starting the process and then attaching the debugger

```
            SingleLineTest();
            MultiLineTest();
            SingleLineTest();
            MultiLineTest();
            SingleLineTest();
            MultiLineTest();
--------------------------------
SingleLineTest()
           Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
00000000  push        ebp 
00000001  mov         ebp,esp 
00000003  push        edi 
00000004  push        esi 
00000005  push        ebx 
00000006  mov         ecx,685D2C68h 
0000000b  call        FFD91F70 
00000010  mov         esi,eax 
00000012  mov         ecx,esi 
00000014  call        681D68BC 
            stopwatch.Start();
00000019  cmp         byte ptr [esi+14h],0 
0000001d  jne         0000002E 
0000001f  call        681FB3E4 
00000024  mov         dword ptr [esi+0Ch],eax 
00000027  mov         dword ptr [esi+10h],edx 
0000002a  mov         byte ptr [esi+14h],1 
            int count = 0;
0000002e  xor         edi,edi 
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++i)
00000030  xor         edx,edx 
            {
                count += i % 16 == 0 ? 1 : 0;
00000032  mov         eax,edx 
00000034  and         eax,8000000Fh 
00000039  jns         00000040 
0000003b  dec         eax 
0000003c  or          eax,0FFFFFFF0h 
0000003f  inc         eax 
00000040  test        eax,eax 
00000042  je          00000048 
00000044  xor         eax,eax 
00000046  jmp         0000004D 
00000048  mov         eax,1 
0000004d  add         edi,eax 
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++i)
0000004f  inc         edx 
00000050  cmp         edx,3B9ACA00h 
00000056  jl          00000032 
            }
            stopwatch.Stop();
00000058  mov         ecx,esi 
0000005a  call        6820F390 
            Console.WriteLine("Single-line test --> Count: {0}, Time: {1}", count, stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
0000005f  mov         ecx,6A8B29B4h 
00000064  call        FFD91F70 
00000069  mov         ecx,eax 
0000006b  mov         dword ptr [ecx+4],edi 
0000006e  mov         ebx,ecx 
00000070  mov         ecx,6A8AA240h 
00000075  call        FFD91F70 
0000007a  mov         edi,eax 
0000007c  mov         ecx,esi 
0000007e  call        6820ACB8 
00000083  push        edx 
00000084  push        eax 
00000085  push        0 
00000087  push        2710h 
0000008c  call        6AFF48BC 
00000091  mov         dword ptr [edi+4],eax 
00000094  mov         dword ptr [edi+8],edx 
00000097  mov         esi,edi 
00000099  call        6A457010 
0000009e  push        ebx 
0000009f  push        esi 
000000a0  mov         ecx,eax 
000000a2  mov         edx,dword ptr ds:[039F2030h] 
000000a8  mov         eax,dword ptr [ecx] 
000000aa  mov         eax,dword ptr [eax+3Ch] 
000000ad  call        dword ptr [eax+1Ch] 
000000b0  pop         ebx 
        }
000000b1  pop         esi 
000000b2  pop         edi 
000000b3  pop         ebp 
000000b4  ret
```

Multi first:

```
            MultiLineTest();

            SingleLineTest();
            MultiLineTest();
            SingleLineTest();
            MultiLineTest();
            SingleLineTest();
            MultiLineTest();
--------------------------------
SingleLineTest()
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
00000000  push        ebp 
00000001  mov         ebp,esp 
00000003  push        edi 
00000004  push        esi 
00000005  push        ebx 
00000006  mov         ecx,685D2C68h 
0000000b  call        FFF31EA0 
00000010  mov         esi,eax 
00000012  mov         dword ptr [esi+4],0 
00000019  mov         dword ptr [esi+8],0 
00000020  mov         byte ptr [esi+14h],0 
00000024  mov         dword ptr [esi+0Ch],0 
0000002b  mov         dword ptr [esi+10h],0 
            stopwatch.Start();
00000032  cmp         byte ptr [esi+14h],0 
00000036  jne         00000047 
00000038  call        682AB314 
0000003d  mov         dword ptr [esi+0Ch],eax 
00000040  mov         dword ptr [esi+10h],edx 
00000043  mov         byte ptr [esi+14h],1 
            int count = 0;
00000047  xor         edi,edi 
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++i)
00000049  xor         edx,edx 
            {
                count += i % 16 == 0 ? 1 : 0;
0000004b  mov         eax,edx 
0000004d  and         eax,8000000Fh 
00000052  jns         00000059 
00000054  dec         eax 
00000055  or          eax,0FFFFFFF0h 
00000058  inc         eax 
00000059  test        eax,eax 
0000005b  je          00000061 
0000005d  xor         eax,eax 
0000005f  jmp         00000066 
00000061  mov         eax,1 
00000066  add         edi,eax 
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++i)
00000068  inc         edx 
00000069  cmp         edx,3B9ACA00h 
0000006f  jl          0000004B 
            }
            stopwatch.Stop();
00000071  mov         ecx,esi 
00000073  call        682BF2C0 
            Console.WriteLine("Single-line test --> Count: {0}, Time: {1}", count, stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
00000078  mov         ecx,6A8B29B4h 
0000007d  call        FFF31EA0 
00000082  mov         ecx,eax 
00000084  mov         dword ptr [ecx+4],edi 
00000087  mov         ebx,ecx 
00000089  mov         ecx,6A8AA240h 
0000008e  call        FFF31EA0 
00000093  mov         edi,eax 
00000095  mov         ecx,esi 
00000097  call        682BABE8 
0000009c  push        edx 
0000009d  push        eax 
0000009e  push        0 
000000a0  push        2710h 
000000a5  call        6B0A47EC 
000000aa  mov         dword ptr [edi+4],eax 
000000ad  mov         dword ptr [edi+8],edx 
000000b0  mov         esi,edi 
000000b2  call        6A506F40 
000000b7  push        ebx 
000000b8  push        esi 
000000b9  mov         ecx,eax 
000000bb  mov         edx,dword ptr ds:[038E2034h] 
000000c1  mov         eax,dword ptr [ecx] 
000000c3  mov         eax,dword ptr [eax+3Ch] 
000000c6  call        dword ptr [eax+1Ch] 
000000c9  pop         ebx 
        }
000000ca  pop         esi 
000000cb  pop         edi 
000000cc  pop         ebp 
000000cd  ret
```

Comment: See those `nop` instructions?  I think this isn't optimized, running inside the debugger suppressed optimizations.

Comment: @Ben yes, I attached the debugger later, output is a bit different, though.