# Where does Normal Jit save cache?

Tags: .net, jit

I read the the different between Normal Jit and Econo Jit is the Normal saves cache for the machine code.

I didn't get, What is this cache? where is it stored? How would the Econo Jit executable be slower once there is no cache for the already compiled to machine code one? it and I found no further details while re-searching.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where is the .NET JIT-compiled code cached?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295622/where-is-the-net-jit-compiled-code-cached)

Comment: It's been a long time since I have heard the word EconoJIT. Obsolete. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14547875/122718